# Access intranet URL on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

In my company we have some internal URLs what we would like to link to in the cloud.

I've created an SPFx web part and try to display an HTML img tag with the URL of `http://intranetserver/MyPics/user123/headshot.jpg`

but I get

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Is there something I need to do within my web part solution or Azure to allow this access?

Comment: You can't expose an INTRAnet host. They are running in a private IP subnet with a private hostname not resolved in public DNS. Plus it's considered a security problem because you're opening the attack vector and leaking internal information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into an SSL issue because you're trying to load content from a non-secure URL (http instead of https), not to mention it's from another domain, so cross-domain concerns play into it as well.

The two best choices are:

- Upload the image(s) directly to your SPO site, in the default images document library

  - (or another, more private document library if necessary)
- Create an SSL certificate and place it on the internal server that's hosting the images

Comment: They should install a valid certificate anyways but the host won't be available through public internet anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I just need to get that URL to be https and it should be ok?

Comment: @DanielW. It's only an issue if they access the SPO site from outside their internal network; many tenants are restricted to be accessible only when on the work network, either sitting on-site or connected via VPN, etc. But that does raise a good point.

Comment: @PeteWhelan See my response to Daniel's comment above--does your company allow SPO tenant access from anywhere or do you need to be connected to your internal company network to access sites on that tenant? (And to answer your question, yes, you should get that URL to be HTTPS. Even if other steps are required, that is a good security step to take for all servers where possible).